# Can I replace in runtime a chunk created by webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, architecture, lazy-loading

We're thinking about how to design our architecture.

We have a main application - `mainApp` 
This mainApp is a hosting platform for other child apps.
We use webpack to bundle everything, and using System.import() for each app to get the lazy loading.

Our result looks like:

```
main.bundle.js
0.chunk.js
1.chunk.js
2.chunk.js
3.chunk.js
```

Where each chunk is an isolated application, developed by a certain team.

We're looking for the ability to upgrade a child app independently, in run-time, without re-bundling the whole application.

A team working on a specific app, would have only it's own child-app and the main app. 
This team updates their app and re-bundling, they will get:

```
main.bundle.js
2.chunk.js
```

**My question is:**
Can I take the new `2.chunk.js` and drop it to production?

**Notes:**

1. A child app doesn't require modules from another child app
2. I tried to do what I suggest here but got a collision in the modules
   ids within the webpack's output, but also - I got different chunk
   names, so I thought maybe it's related.

Comment: Did you get the solution?. I think module federation can be used to isolate applications